# How can I make box shadow show over the next element in a container?

Tags: html, css, hover, flexbox, box-shadow

Please see this code: http://codepen.io/Varin/pen/kkGgVd

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="outside2">
        <div class="inside2">
          <span class="text"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="outside2">
        <div class="inside2">
          <span class="text"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="outside2">
        <div class="inside2">
          <span class="text"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And CSS

```
$color1 : rgba(123,223,12,0.66);
$color2 : rgba(23,43,122,0.66);

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #222222;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  //height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
}

.text:after {
  content: 'Some info about the product and features, the history of the company lorem ipsum and so on.';
}
.outside2 {
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/wavy-letter-v-logo-in-abstract-style_1017-1976.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  &:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 101px 100px $color1, 0px 0px 201px 56px $color1;
    .text {
      opacity:1;
      transition-delay: 0.2s;
    }
  }
  .text {
    color: #fff;
    opacity:0;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  }
}
```

In the last row where both types of box shadow are displayed on hover, 1st elements' shadow is under the second element. Only the 3rd elements' shadow shows over the 2nd element.

I could play with z-index I guess, but is there a way to make sure that all box-shadows are always on top of everything else? Is this something to do with flexbox?

Comment: Just add `z-index: 1` to `.outside2:hover`. You don't need any CSS positioning.

Comment: Thanks, adding z-index:1 to :hover works great. This actually solved a lot of my issues. Still learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add to your block `position: relative` on hover and give him biggest z-index.
[JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/ch68kpx4/)